# How to refresh the form after the form load

Tags: codenameone

I see the images or empty space from previous form on current form. This is sporadic. I would like to do a refresh on the form once again after navigating to the form. repaint() is the only method I can use to achieve this or any other work around. Please advise.

Comment: Have you tried revalidate?

Comment: Yes.I did. It has no effect. Thx

Comment: Actually don't do repaint or revalidate when showing a form for the first time. It might collide wit the transition and trigger something when both forms still have permission to draw to the screen. We'll need an isolated test case that reproduces this in order to address this.

Comment: Shai..this is only happenign on iOS devices and not encountering on android devices. It is very hard to isolate the issue because this is sporadic.Initially this form used to display the buttons of previous form on current form and when I touch the screen  those buttons will disappear. So I did setVisible(false) for my all forms while navigating from one another. So because of that now empty space is appearing on top of the container list. Is there something I can do to work around this issue. Please advise.

Comment: Is this something to do with the white background I have selected for my App. Is it due to white color Native on IOS don't have proper transparency setting.Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure you add/remove/change any UI components in this block?

```
Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {};
```

I'll usually put the revalidate() at the very end of this block. Also, I believe for forms containing lists I've had some issues with revalidate() and use animateLayout(250) instead.

Comment: I'm using AppointmentsContainerInfinite and manually refresh the container based on user action I'm not checking anything in callSerially. User can refresh the list only clicking on sidemenu or hold and swipe refresh on the container. Please advise.

Comment: Do you mean InfiniteScrollAdapter or InfiniteContainer? Can you show some code? Like I said though, I believe you are supposed to put the revalidate() statement within the callSerially() block.